# Setup Google Ads Conversion Tracking With Firebase For iOS App - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-ads-api, apptrackingtransparency

I'm trying to set up conversion tracking with Firebase. I followed Google's instructions but no conversions are showing.

**[Google's Post](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/13823256?sjid=2284422099915484085-EU&visit_id=638471317692651964-1580978031&rd=1)**

Here is what I've tried so far:

**Code Implementation**

1. Set up Firebase Analytics.
2. Logged event after In-App Purchase. `.logEvent()`
3. Showed ATT prompt after a successful purchase. `ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization`

**Firestore Console**

1. Entered App Store ID in profile.
2. Integrated Google Ads.

**Google Ads**

1. Created a conversion action.

Now, I know some people allowed tracking because I log their input.

Am I Missing something?
Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Last I checked only about 4% of people say yes to ATT, but its been a long time since I set this all up. Make sure that you have the ad network ids setup too. Go through all the documentation it is a lot of little stuff.

Comment: What are Ad Network IDs?
From Firebase docs: `For your convenience, the SDK automatically registers your app with Apple for ad network attribution with SKAdNetwork`